# Windows Update has updates for programs I don't have

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, windows-update, microsoft-office-2013

I just installed Microsoft Visio 2013. This is the only program I have that's part of Office 2013. After I restarted, Windows Update suddenly popped up with 23 new updates, all related to Office 2013, but only two are actually for Visio 2013! Most of them just say "Update for Office 2013", but there are updates Lync, OneNote, and SkyDrive Pro, none of which I own.

Do I really have to install all these updates and if not how do I get rid of them?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

### Enterprise-minded policy

You say you are receiving these via Windows Update. That means you have the MSI version of Microsoft Visio 2013. Microsoft sells this version to Enterprise customers only. Therefore, it has an Enterprise-minded update policy in place.

It is quite simple: Enterprise customers don't mind downloading a couple of extra gigabytes if that means more safety for their business continuity. Therefore, Microsoft policy is that the moment you install an Office suite, you are offered every single update that applies to the most exhaustive Microsoft Office suite installation. It doesn't matter that you don't have those components installed right now. What matters is, when you install one, it is installed with the latest update already in place. There is no chance for an attack on the new arrival. (Also, please bear in mind that some Office components come as part of other apps, like LOBs and Visual Studio.)

### What about consumers?

Starting with Microsoft Office 2010, consumers install Microsoft Office using Click-to-Run, which only updates the files that they possess. As for the files they don't possess, only the latest versions are downloaded anyway.

### Do I really have to install all these updates?

Yes, per your Enterprise support contract with Microsoft, you *have* to! Microsoft support policy is: If you don't install the fixes we give you, don't come crying to us when you have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

All Office tools share a lot of components and so you get updates for the shared files. I also get Office 2007 Updates offered even if I don't have it, because I use Visual Studio 2008 which uses some Office files.

Comment: If you see my question linked to above, I went so far as to carefully check each KB article's updated file list and search my system for those files. Not only were the files due to be updated completely missing (not a surprise obviously), but even when I deliberately allowed a few of the updates to install the new files did not appear on my system. So basically it incorrectly detects updates that a system requires, wastes time and especially bandwidth downloading them, only to finally not install anything because those updates aren't applicable at all! Ridiculous, to say the least.